# How do I test the visual accessibility of web pages under development?

Tags: css, browser, accessibility, colors

When developing websites, I'd like to be able to quickly switch to "what does this look like to a person with certain types of color blindness?"

I've found [Visicheck](http://www.vischeck.com/), which will show you approximations of what an image or a public web page will look like.

Is there something I could use on my local development before a site goes live?  A Firefox plugin perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to work on ffx2 https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7313. Doesn't show you what it loks like, but it does give you a table of elements of the site, highlighting those that coudl be problematic.

Why not download [ffx portable 2](https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=151265&package_id=283201) and install it on that.

*edit turns out a beta of it is available for ffx3

Answer (score 2):

You could screen-shot it and send it to me :)

Comment: Humorous, but not easily automated.  And I suspect you'd get tired of me sending you hundreds of screen shots every week :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself yet, but [here's a Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5614) that is supposed to do just that.

There are various-types of color-blindness. So the best way to maximize the accessibility of your site is to simply test the contrast levels of your design (background vs. text). [Here's an article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200709/10_colour_contrast_checking_tools_to_improve_the_accessibility_of_your_design/) containing a list of resources/tools for doing so. This will help your visitors read your content in poor lighting conditions, using poor displays, and who are color-blind or have poor eyesight.

One advantage to checking contrast levels is that it works for all types of color-perceptions, and it won't force you to use colors & hues that don't match in regular color-perception.